# No traffic with Wireguard on Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, dns, wireguard

I'm trying to use Wireguard on Ubuntu 22.04. The same server-client-configuration is working without an issue for Windows and Android.

I'm not the administrator for the server side, but got the following configuration for the user side:

```
[Interface]
Address = 140.22.48.120/24
DNS = 140.22.48.103, 140.22.192.100, 140.22.192.101
PrivateKey = <privatekey

[Peer]
PublicKey = <publickey>
PresharedKey = <presharedkey>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 140.22.48.100:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

When using `sudo wg quick-up wg0`, the following output is generated:

```
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 140.22.48.120/24 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1460 up dev wg0
[#] resolvconf -a wg0 -m 0 -x
[#] wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
[#] nft -f /dev/fd/63
```

The handshake seems to work. Yet, when opening up any webpage, the connection times out.

```
interface: wg0
  public key: <differentpublickey>
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 60246
  fwmark: 0xca6c

peer: <publickey>
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: 140.22.48.100:51820
  allowed ips: 0.0.0.0/0
  transfer: 0 B received, 3.32 KiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds
```

The `public key` in the second line is different to the `<publickey>` in line 7.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: Are you sure the port is 51825? The default is 51820

Comment: It is indeed 51820, I renamed it for this example, now I see that this is not a good intent :-)
I'll edit it to 51820.

Answer (score 3):

`Address = 140.22.48.120/24` tells wireguard that the interface belongs to a network where the network covers 140.22.48.0-140.22.48.255. This means that any packets to any of those IP's can be sent on the interface, without going via a router.

However, your wireguard server is *also* inside this network - `140.22.48.100`. This means that after wireguard comes up, wireguard tells the kernel that `140.22.48.100` can be reached by sending a packet over the wireguard interface.

This is basic TCP/IP networking. `/24` is called [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

Answer (score 1):

Wow, after I had this issue for almost a year, I've finally found the solution.

Instead of `Address = 140.22.48.120/24`, inspired by [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/1217150/1755636) I've tried passing 32 bits by setting it to `Address = 140.22.48.120/32`, and it just works.

I don't know why that is, maybe someone has an explanation?

Comment: Sure. See my answer :)